# Can I make Apache more secure by removing read access from the others group?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, security

It says in the [Apache documentation security tips](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/misc/security_tips.html) to set your server root directory and sub-directories to be owned by root, with a group of root and to not be writeable by non-root users. However it also says to change the mode to 755 which gives read access to others. So, as an admin, I can create a new user who by default can access the Apache configuration files. Wouldn't it be more secure to change the mode to 750? Apart from the inconvenience of having to sudo in order to view the files is there any other disadvantage to doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location where config files for Apache are stored in Ubuntu by default, is already only writeable by the root user. The files however, must be readable by non-root, as the *httpd* daemon does not run as root.